# Is there a way to run Android TV in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, android-tv

I want to try out Android TV and possibly develop an app for it. I want to see the OS first though. Is there a way to run Android TV in as a virtual machine, for instance with VirtualBox?

Comment: You can use the Android emulator with the Android TV system image that is available via the Android SDK Manager.

Comment: A great question; I use the "Android X86 Project" images in Virtual Box everyday for debugging and dev work. [Android X86 porject](http://www.android-x86.org/) These are far superior to working with the Google supplied Emulator. The Android TV image on the emulator is even lamer. Perhaps Google could work with X86 project to provide a superior solution.

Comment: @dextor Thank you, using the dev tools is a good idea.

Comment: @Peter The project seems cool, however it seems they don't have a port for Android TV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment to the OP, your best bet is to install the Android SDK and [fetch the Android TV system images](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html). Then, create an [Android Virtual Device](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/avd-manager.html) (AVD) with the TV image and run the emulator.

You won't have any of the apps that are preinstalled in, say, a Nexus Player, **but you will get the idea** around how this version of Android runs and what it is capable of.

[*PRO TIP*: if you're on OSX, using the x86 one results in HAXM acceleration enabled --> the emulator runs really smooth]